# Very big integer numbers in python numba

Tags: python, numba

I am working on cryptography which includes very large integer numbers of around `2048` bits size. I have return my algorithm in python and working fine. Now, i need to accelerate this algorithm with GPU. So, i am using numba for accelaration. I am getting following error. Please assist me in working very large integer numbers.

> ValueError: Int value is too large:
>   92258844410360056197837473187695644910346254368316703862914922507771377266980480337680534948953927388850060454071957519321942465209478761155937984413689971094452635917678279011141842700271439588766362468089643758626551820024243785880479259172494136586386527772928225026351839534218119545890907368759523376112

Comment: please add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Oblivion why do you need an example. Just plug the number in a `@jit` function

Answer (score 3):

[numba doesn't support bigint](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5005). Only integer types supported by NumPy can be used. Apparently there are no plans for this to change in the future.

Comment: The unlimited size integers provided by Python are a unique language feature.  I'm not surprised to see reasonable limits placed on integers in other contexts.